# Types and comparisons in R

Tags: r, types, dataframe, type-conversion

I've been working with R for a month or so, and my comprehension of some subtleties is still quite superficial.
I have had an issue, which I managed to solve (details below), but I still can't explain precisely why it did not work with the first solution.
Note that the example below makes no practical sense for I have simplified it as much as possible so that the problem is quite clear.

ISSUE :
Given a data frame with 4 columns (email, first, last, company) :

```
> users <- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 0, 4, dimnames=list(c(), c("email", "first", "last", "company"))), stringsAsFactors=F)
> users[1,] <- c("robert@redford.com", "Robert", "Redford", "Paramount")
> users[2,] <- c("julia@roberts.com", "Erin", "B.", "Hinkley")
> users[3,] <- c("matt@damon.com", "Will", "H.", "Stanford")
> users[4,] <- c("john@malkovitch.com", "John", "M.", "JM")
```

I take one particular row :

```
> user <- users[3,]
```

When I try to subset the dataframe on a criteria which could have lead to return the previously mentioned row, it returns no result.

```
> users[users$email == user["email"],]
[1] email   first   last    company
<0 lignes> (ou 'row.names' de longueur nulle)
```

I instantly thought it was a casting issue (sorry for this bad one)

```
> users[users$email == as.character(user["email"]),]
           email first last  company
3 matt@damon.com  Will   H. Stanford
```

However, when I tried to figure out where exactly the issue was, and tried this :

```
> users[users$email == "matt@damon.com",]
           email first last  company
3 matt@damon.com  Will   H. Stanford

> user["email"] == "matt@damon.com"
  email
3  TRUE

> users[3,]$email == user$email
[1] TRUE
```

I got quite confused :

- First, I thought about it as a math problem : `if A == B and B == C, then A == C` (according to Captain Obvious). So, just replacing a member A by another member B which is supposed to be equal to A (given the "TRUE" statement) in some expression should have no impact on the result of this expression.
- `3  TRUE != [1] TRUE`. I think `[1] TRUE` is a logical vector of size 1 which first element is TRUE. `3  TRUE` is (1x1) matrix row, which column "email" value is TRUE.

My problem is with consistency : either two objects of equal content but different types should be equal, or they should be different. I have a problem with "Sometimes there is type inference, and sometimes not". Is there a rule I can't see beyond this behavior ? (I guess there is one)

Another expression of the behavior I'd like to get is this one :

```
> unique(users$email) == "matt@damon.com"
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> unique(users$email) == user["email"]
  email
3 FALSE
```

Obviously R does get what I want (considering the fact that it gives me the matching row). But I can't explain (nor use) the result of the second statement.
Any explanations / thoughts?

Comment: try `user[["email"]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in normal list situations

```
users$email == user[["email"]]
```

however in data.frames things get inconsistent/ a lot worse!

```
tdf=data.frame(matrix(1:100,10,10))
tdf[] # returns data.frame everything
tdf[1] # returns data.frame first column
tdf[1,1] # returns object as type of the object...
tdf[,1] # returns a vector of the first column
tdf[1,] # returns a data.frame of the first row # eeeeeugh... that is odd....
tdf[2:4] # returns a data.frame with 3 columns
tdf[1,2:4] # returns a data.frame of the first row of 3 colums
tdf[2:4,2:4] # returns a 3x3 data.frame
tdf[2:4,1] # returns a vector of 2:4 row and 1st column
tdf[,2:4] # returns a data.frame with 3 columns
```

then there is also the double [[]]

do note that in data.frames things get horribly annoying and fugly

```
tdf[[1]] # gives the first row as a vector
tdf[[1,1]] # gives first element
```

and pretty much all other combinations gives errors

and assigning stuff to a data.frame or matrix, is an even bigger mess!

Comment: I'm downvoting because of your disparaging language.  While use of the `[` and `[[` operators can be confusing at first, calling this a "mess" or "fugly" is inappropriate and unhelpful.

Comment: Just came back to this question with a bit more of R experience. It appears that your answer is good, and addresses my question, which I didn't see at first, although I don't really agree with you on the 'messy' part !
Sorry for the 18-months delay ;-)